# After page refresh mui textfield loses css style

Tags: css, next.js, material-ui

I use material ui library, but for some reason if you go to the page with links on the site everything is fine, but if you refresh the page the form does not load its basic styles.[this is how the forms look when the page is refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ffc6.png)[this is how the forms look if you click on them with links on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu2Ao.png)

````
import styles from './Settings.module.scss'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { MainLayout } from '../../../layouts/MainLayout'
import ArrowBackIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIosOutlined'
import {
    Box,
    InputAdornment,
    Paper,
    TextField,
    Typography
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { MuiThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core'

interface SettingsMainProps {
    id: string
    fullName: string
}

const SettingsMain: React.FC<SettingsMainProps> = ({ id, fullName }) => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState(fullName)

    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const handleUserNameChange = event => {
        const value = event.target.value
        if (value.length <= 30) {
            setUserName(value)
            if (/[<>{}"№'`^*[\]@]/.test(value)) {
                setError('Неподходящая длина или формат никнейма')
            } else {
                setError('')
            }
        } else {
            setError('Неподходящая длина или формат никнейма')
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <style>
                {`
          :root {
            --wrapper-padding-top: 70px;
            .content {
                --max-width-content: 960px;
            }
          }
        `}
            </style>
            <MainLayout>
                <div
                    className={`${styles.page} ${styles.userSettings} ${styles.page__contentSidebar}`}
                >
                    <div className={styles.page__content}>
                        <div
                            className={`${styles.userSettings__content} ${styles.islandBg} ${styles.islandRound} ${styles.island}`}
                        >
                            <Link
                                className={`${styles.settingsHeader} ${styles.userSettings__header}`}
                                href={`/profile/${id}`}
                            >
                                <ArrowBackIcon
                                    style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}
                                    className={`${styles.settingsHeader__icon} ${styles.icon} ${styles.icon__arrow_left}`}
                                />
                            </Link>
                            <div className={styles.userSettings__container}>
                                <div className={styles.userProfile}>
                                    <div className={styles.formSection}>
                                        <label className={styles.formSection__label}>
                                            Отображаемое имя
                                        </label>
                                        <form>
                                            <TextField
                                                size='small'
                                                label=''
                                                variant='outlined'
                                                fullWidth
                                                required
                                                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
                                                error={!!error}
                                                helperText={error}
                                                InputProps={{
                                                    endAdornment: (
                                                        <InputAdornment position='end'>
                                                            {30 - userName.length}
                                                        </InputAdornment>
                                                    )
                                                }}
                                                value={userName} // Используйте состояние userName вместо fullName
                                                onChange={handleUserNameChange} // Обработчик изменения значения имени пользователя
                                            />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={styles.formSection}>
                                        <label className={styles.formSection__label}>
                                            Описание к блогу
                                        </label>
                                        <form>
                                            <TextField
                                                size='small'
                                                label=''
                                                variant='outlined'
                                                fullWidth
                                                required
                                                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
                                                value={userName} // Используйте состояние userName вместо fullName
                                                onChange={handleUserNameChange} // Обработчик изменения значения имени пользователя
                                            />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={styles.formSection}>
                                        <label className={styles.formSection__label}>
                                            Лента по умолчанию
                                        </label>
                                        <form>
                                            <TextField
                                                size='small'
                                                label=''
                                                variant='outlined'
                                                fullWidth
                                                required
                                                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
                                                value={userName} // Используйте состояние userName вместо fullName
                                                onChange={handleUserNameChange} // Обработчик изменения значения имени пользователя
                                            />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`${styles.userSettings__sidebar} ${styles.userSettings__sidebar}`}
                    >
                        <div className={`${styles.userSettings__stickyContainer}`}>
                            <div
                                className={`${styles.islandBg} ${styles.island} ${styles.islandRound} ${styles.sidebarNavigation__desktop}`}
                            ></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MainLayout>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SettingsMain

```page where I use forms


I tried to write my own style, but it conflicts with basic mui styles.
````